# Is Twitter's Tweet_ID unique across twitter platform?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy

I'm writing a script to process and store million of tweets. The way my code works is that Tweet's ID is stored as **_id** for MongoDB document to make it unique across my DB.
What I observe is that Tweet ID doesn't appear to be unique and I get duplicate key error when writing tweets for different users to DB.
Documentation of snowflake (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/twitter-ids) gives an overview how the tweet ID is generated and it appears that it should be unique across the twitter DB.
Can some confirm if the twitter's Tweet ID is actually unique across their DB?
This is how my code works:

```
def write_tweets_to_db(tweets):
    processed_tweets = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        processed_tweets = process_tweet(tweet)  # This is where I convert tweepy object to dict and 
                                                 # set _id key to tweet ID
    for tweet in processed_tweets:
        try:
            collection.insert_one(tweet)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error while writing tweet to DB | Error: {}'.format(e))

# Error while writing tweet to DB | Error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: [DB].[collection] index: _id_ dup key: { _id: 1235024705523863552 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweet IDs are indeed unique. You should always use the string variant of the ID to avoid issues with JavaScript and other languages that cannot handle large integers converting the numbers.

Comment: Exactly what I found to be true. I tested it by grabbing all tweets of some 100 users and tried to find any repeating tweet_ids (none found). So I checked my code and the cause of duplicate key error was duplicate twitter IDs in the seeding list. Thank you for clarification!!